# The connection between the supremums of a function sequence, and the supremum of the limit fumction

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose we have a function series $\mathbb f_n(x)$ that converge uniformly to $\mathbb f(x)$ for every $x \in [a,b]$ , and suppose that for each $n \in \mathbb N$ and for every $x \in [a,b]$  : $\lvert \mathbb f_n(x)\rvert \le M_n$, i.e $\mathbb f_n(x)$ is bounded for each $n \in \mathbb N$.

I can also prove that $f(x)$ is bounded by some $M_0 \in \Bbb R$.

I am wondering however - does all of the above is enough to prove that the sequence $M_n$ converge to $M_0$?

If the statement is just not true, can someone give me a counter example?

Comment: I guess you mean that $M_n$ and $M_0$ are not just bounds, but suprema ?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Can you prove that for any normed space $(E,N)$, the function $N:E\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous with respect to the norm topology on $E$ ?

Comment: what does E stand for?

Comment: Like I said, any normed space. Here the idea is to apply that to $E=B(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, the space of bounded real functions, with the norm $N(f)=||f||_\infty$.

Comment: Im afraid it's beyond my current education. Is there any other method you can recommend? Im also assuming that my statement is true and I just haven't thought of a way to prove it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, by contradiction,that $(M_n)_n$ does not converge to $M_0$. Then for some $r>0$ the set $$S=\{n:|M_0-M_n|>r\}$$ is infinite.  And $\{n:\sup_x|f(x)-f_n(x)|\geq r/2\}$ is finite .So there exists $n\in S$ with $\sup_x |f_n(x)-f(x)|<r/2$.  For such $n$ we have $$(1)\quad M_0\leq M_n+r/2.$$ But there exists $x_n$ with $|f_n(x_n)|>M_n-r/2$. This gives $$M_0\geq |f(x_n)\geq|f_n(x_n)|-|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|>   |f(x_n)|-r/2>(M_n-r/2)-r/2=M_n-r$$  from which we have$$(2)\quad M_0\geq M_n -r.$$ From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have $ M_n+r/2\geq M_0\geq M_n-r,$ so $|M_0-M_n|\leq r,$ a contradiction, because $n\in S.$

Answer (score -1):

Hint : you may prove that in general if $f$ and $g$ are bounded functions then $$| \,||f||_\infty - ||g||_\infty | \leqslant ||f - g||_\infty$$
where as usual $||f||_\infty = \sup |f(x)|$. You can take your inspiration in the proof of the basic inequality $|\, |x|-|y|\,| \leqslant |x-y|$.

Then apply to $g=f_n$.